# How to delete Azure Static Web App branch preview environments when deleting source branch in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

**Background**

I am using [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops/) for hosting the source of my web application and building/deploying the application to an [Azure Static Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/products/app-service/static/).

I am using the "branch preview environments" of Static Web App like this ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/branch-environments?tabs=azure-devops)):

```
steps:
  ...
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      ...
      production_branch: 'main'
```

This works fine so far. For example, if I use a branch "dev", a corresponding branch environment is being created.

**Question**

How can I automatically delete the Azure static web app branch preview environment once the branch it was created for is being deleted?

**Use Azure cli?**

The only approach I found so far is using Azure CLI - but how to automate?

```
az staticwebapp environment delete --name my-static-app \
  --environment-name an-env-name --subscription my-sub
```

Comment: I opened a GitHub issue describing this feature request https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/956

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by creating a separate pipeline triggered by the `main` branch. The pipeline removes all deployments that don't have an open pull request.

Here is the pipeline, basically just calling a node script that takes care of the cleanup:

```
name: Cleanup static web apps

trigger:
  - main

# Add the following variables into devops:
# - DEVOPS_PAT: your personal access token for DevOps
# - AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: the subscription in azure under which your swa lives
variables:
  NPM_CONFIG_CACHE: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm
  DEVOPS_ORG_URL: "https://dev.azure.com/feedm3"
  DEVOPS_PROJECT: "azure-playground"
  AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME: "react-app"

jobs:
- job: cleanup_preview_environments_job
  displayName: Cleanup
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
      restoreKeys: |
        npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
      path: $(NPM_CONFIG_CACHE)
    displayName: "Cache npm"

  - script: |
      npm ci
    displayName: "Install dependencies"
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "test-service-connection-name"
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        npm run ci:cleanup-deployments
    displayName: "Cleanup outdated deployments"
```

This is the actual script that removes the deployments:

```js
import { getPersonalAccessTokenHandler, WebApi } from "azure-devops-node-api";
import { exec as callbackExec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const exec = promisify(callbackExec);

const DEVOPS_ORG_URL = process.env["DEVOPS_ORG_URL"] as string;
const DEVOPS_PROJECT = process.env["DEVOPS_PROJECT"] as string;
const DEVOPS_PAT = process.env["DEVOPS_PAT"] as string;
const AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION = process.env["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION"] as string;
const AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME = process.env["AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME"] as string;

const ALWAYS_DEPLOYED_BRANCHES = ['main'];

const REPO_ID = process.env['BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID'] as string;

const getAllStaticWebAppDeployments = async (): Promise<{ name: string; sourceBranch: string, hostname: string }[]> => {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`az staticwebapp environment list --name ${AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME} --subscription ${AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION}`);
  if (stderr) {
    console.error('Command failed!', stderr);
    throw new Error(stderr);
  }

  return JSON.parse(stdout);
}

const run = async () => {
  console.log(`Cleanup outdated deployments ${{REPO_ID, DEVOPS_PROJECT, AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME}}...`)

  const webAppDeployments = await getAllStaticWebAppDeployments();

  // post comment
  const authHandler = getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(DEVOPS_PAT);
  const connection = new WebApi(DEVOPS_ORG_URL, authHandler);

  await connection.connect();

  const gitApi = await connection.getGitApi(`${DEVOPS_ORG_URL}/${DEVOPS_PROJECT}`);

  // status 1 is active (PullRequestStatus type)
  const activePullRequests = await gitApi.getPullRequests(REPO_ID, { status: 1 });
  const activePullRequestBranches = activePullRequests.map(pr => pr.sourceRefName).filter(Boolean).map(fullBranchName => fullBranchName!.split('/')[2]);

  // main deployment should always be alive
  activePullRequestBranches.push(...ALWAYS_DEPLOYED_BRANCHES);

  const outdatedDeployments = webAppDeployments.filter(deployment => {
    return !activePullRequestBranches.includes(deployment.sourceBranch);
  })
  console.log('Deployments to delete:', outdatedDeployments);

  for await (const deployment of outdatedDeployments) {
    const deploymentName = deployment.name;
    console.log(`Deleting deployment ${deploymentName}...`);

    /**
     * Deletion works, but ends with an irrelevant error.
     */
    try {
      const { stderr } = await exec(`az staticwebapp environment delete --name ${AZURE_STATIC_WEBAPP_NAME} --subscription ${AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION}  --environment-name ${deploymentName} --yes`);
      if (stderr) {
        console.error('Could not delete deployment ', deploymentName);
      } else {
        console.log('Deleted deployment ', deploymentName);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Deleted deployment ', deploymentName);
    }
  }

  console.log('Outdated deployments cleared!')
}

await run();
```

The full repo can be found here: https://github.com/feedm3/learning-azure-swa-devops

Answer (score 0):

A simplified approach if it works for you is to have a cron that deletes all the environments every night except for production and develop (any any other you might specify).

```
variables:
  - group: your-variable-group


trigger: none
pr: none


schedules:
  - cron: "0 11 * * MON-FRI"  # UTC
    displayName: Cleanup Schedule
    branches:
      include:
      - main
    always: true


steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Cleanup Azure Static Webapp Branch Environments
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnectionName)
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      
      $webAppName = "$(WebAppName)"
      $environments = az staticwebapp environment list --name $webAppName | ConvertFrom-Json

      $environments | ForEach-Object { 
          $envId = $_.buildId
          if ($envId -ne "default" -and $envId -ne "master" -and $envId -ne "develop") {
              Write-Host "Deleting environment $envId"
              az staticwebapp environment delete --name $webAppName --environment-name $envId --yes | Out-Null
          }
      }
```